# "Specified cast is not valid?"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a code written in c# and I want to compare two "date" values.

the First value is from Database and the second value is string.

I've tried to convert them to date, but this is the error I get all the time

[image]

Bear with me if the answer seems so obvious... I am newbie to c#

---

```
string a, b;
            label32.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            b = label32.Text;
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Rock.accdb";
            con.Open();
            var query1 = "SELECT datear FROM leave WHERE name='" + label14.Text + "'";
            using (var command = new OleDbCommand(query1, con))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
//this is where i get error 
                        a = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("datear")).ToString();
                        DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
                        DateTime f = Convert.ToDateTime(b);
                        d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        f.ToString();
                        if (d > f)
                        {
                            label30.Text = "On Campus";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label30.Text = "Off Campus";
                        }

                    }
                }
            } con.Close();
```

Comment: Any chance you could tell us which line of code is hrowing the xception?

Comment: use command parameters. DO NOT concatenate strings using user input!!

Comment: If you can point out how to compare two date values where one is obtained from database (i use MS Access)

Comment: can you let us have a look a the actual value of datear

Comment: datear = dd-MM-yyyy (like 28-05-2012)

Comment: use a =  reader.GetString(0); on that line

Comment: still the same error... but if you guys have any idea how to get that date value from DB and compare it with other?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this `a = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("datear")).ToString();`

to this

```
a= reader.GetDateTime(0).ToString();
```

Thanks guys for taking time to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DateTime.Parse() method:

Replace this part:

```
DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
DateTime f = Convert.ToDateTime(b);
d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // it just a call of a method, it doesn't change the state of the object
f.ToString(); // it too
```

To:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(a);
DateTime f = DateTime.Parse(b);
if (d > f)
{
    label30.Text = "On Campus";
}
// and so on
```

Comment: maybe you should define your culture, for example,                        dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, yourCulture);

Comment: maybe you misunderstood... the exception is thrown at a = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("datear")).ToString(); i think it has to  do something with getting the value form DB